# Making an element of a 2d array a constant

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

Suppose I have a 2d array as

```
arr[10][15];
```

Now, I want just one element of the array to be constant. I want the arr[9][8] to be fixed to 101:

```
arr[9][8] = 101;
```

I tried this:

```
const arr[9][8] = 101;
```

But the compiler gave errors.
How can I make it constant?

Comment: You can wrap it into a class and check at runtime with an additional table if you have right to write on specific cell.

Comment: why do you want this? Isnt it confusing to have `const` and `non-const` values in the same array? What if you pass the array to a function that expects a non-const / const array?

Comment: If you wrap it in a class you could to an effect do this

Answer (score 4):

You can make the *whole array* constant, but you cannot make just part of it constant.  If part of the array is mutable, then the whole array has to be mutable.